Are singular functions dense in the space of Hölder continuous functions?
We say a non-constant function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ is singular if it is continuous, and in addition differentiable almost everywhere with $f' = 0$ a.e.
For every positive $\alpha < 1$, is the set of singular functions dense in the space of Holder continuous functions of order $\alpha$? Where we equip the space with the norm
$$\|f\|_{C^\alpha} := \sup|f| + \sup_{x, y \in [0, 1]} \frac{|f(y) - f(x)|}{|y - x|^\alpha}.$$
Comments: The prototypical example of a singular function is the Cantor function, which is Hölder continuous of order $\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$.

If you consider the space of all Hölder functions, then that's not separable, so it's very unlikely that such a statement holds. If you take the completion of smooth functions under the Hölder norm, then the answer is yes and it's an easy approximation argument by pieces of Cantor function.

@MartinHairer Hm, why is seperability a necessary condition for the statement to hold? The space of singular functions is surely not countable.

It didn't say it's necessary, just very unlikely based on experience. I would be happy to learn something by being proven wrong...

No. Take $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-\alpha 2^n}\cos(2^{2^n}t)$. This is  $\alpha$-Hölder and there exists $c>0$ such that, for every point $t$, one has
$\limsup_{s \to t} |t-s|^{-\alpha}|f(t)-f(s)| > c$. Take any "singular" functions $g$. Since there is some point $t$ such that $g'(t) = 0$, it follows from the property of $f$ that $\|f-g\|_\alpha \ge c$.

That’s an interesting looking counterexample… could you give a short sketch as to why the limsup is greater than $c$ uniformly?

… although it would suffice to show the limsup is bigger than $0$ on a set of nonzero measure too.

@NateRiver Just consider $|t-s|$ of order $2^{-2^n}$ for large $n$.
